# How to print out / return value from exec

Tags: c, unix, exec

I have a problem regarding the exec() command family. The program stars a while loop, which lasts for 60 seconds. During the while loop a child process gets created every 5 seconds. In that particular child process I need to print the outcome of exec and after that end the child process. How do I get or print the output of exec within the child process?

My code currently looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
    
time_t endwait;
    time_t start = time(NULL);
    time_t seconds = 60;

    endwait = start + seconds;
    while (start < endwait)
    {
        int pid = fork();
        if(pid == 0){
            execlp("date", "+%H:%M:%S", NULL);
            _exit(1);
        }
        sleep(5);
        start = time(NULL);
    }

    printf("end time is %s", ctime(&endwait));

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: If it's successful, `exec()` never returns. There's no outcome to print.

Comment: `exec` does not return unless it fails.  Instead, it causes the child process to replace itself with a new program.  When the child exits, its parent can retrieve its status with `wait` (or other function in the `wait` family), and that exit status could (in a sense) be considered the "outcome" of exec.

Comment: Thanks for the responses! I noticed, that, in my case, exec automatically prints out the result. However, it seems like the arguments I passed [+%H:%M:%S] won't be used. Am I doing something wrong? A solution to this would be much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wait()` to find exec's value.

If `exec` is successful rest of the code "won't used" by the child. But if any error happens it'll continue. Thus using `_exit()` like you did is must. You can test failiure condition via giving wrong commands to `exec` like `execlp("dateCommandThatDoesNotExists", "+%H:%M:%S", NULL);`

Afterwards code will look like below:

```c
#include <sys/wait.h>
// ...
        if(pid == 0){ // Child will ente
            execlp("date", "+%H:%M:%S", NULL);
            _exit(1);
        } else { //  Parent will enter
            int status;
            wait(&status);
            printf("Child exited via: %d\n", status);
        }
// ...
```